# Convert list of dict to csv in python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, inheritance

I have used inheritance for employee details and I'm trying to write it as a csv. My output is in the form of list of dicts and when I'm trying to write it as csv, its not getting printed. 
Here are my codes:

```
import csv
class Employee(object):
    def main(self,name,idno,position,salary):

        self.name=name
        self.idno=idno
        self.position=position
        self.salary=salary

class Employees(Employee):
    def main (self,name,idno,position,salary,age):
        Employee.main(self,name,idno,position,salary)
        self.age=age

    def input(self):

        e1=[]

        n=int(raw_input("Enter the number of employees:"))
        for i in range(n):
            self.name=raw_input("Name:")
            self.idno=raw_input("Idno:")
            self.position=raw_input("Position:")
            self.salary=int(raw_input("Salary:"))
            e2={"Name":self.name,"Idno":self.idno,"Position":self.position, "Salary":self.salary}
            e1.append(e2)
            print e1
```

both list of dict to dict or dict of dict conversion doesnt works and writing to csv doesnt works. Can anyone help me out??

My output should look like this:

```
Name  Idno  Position  Salary
Abc    101   Trainee  12000
Def    102   Trainee  12000
```

Comment: Your `main()` methods look like they should be the `__init__()` method for each class. Then you create instances like this: `employee = Employee(name, idno, position, salary)`, not `employee = Employee(); employee.main(name, idno, position, salary)`.

Comment: Also, why is `self.age` in class `Employees` and not in the base class?

Comment: im trying to use inheritance so i thought of defining age in sub class

Comment: Every employee will have an age, so it makes sense to have that attribute in the `Employee` class.

Comment: @mhawke: Ya that's true but still it was just a practice program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `csv` module of python.

```
data_list = [{...},{...}...]

keys = data_list[0].keys()
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(data_list)
```

Comment: It works. Thanks :) I missed keys=data_list[0]. keys()

Answer (score 0):

Part of the solution is converting your dictionary to a list...The following handles the situation when you have lists within lists within a dictionary...The output is in excel file named 'output' rather than csv.

```
output=[]
for m in dict.keys():
    output.append([m,dict[m]])
output2=[]

for n in output:  
    temp=[]
    for k in n:  
        if isinstance(k,list):   #if it's a list
            for j in k:   #for the items of that list
                if isinstance(j,list):   #if it's a list
                    for i in j:   #for the items of that list
                        temp.append(i)
                else:
                    temp.append(j)
        else:
            temp.append(k)  #if it's not a list, just append
    output2.append(temp)  #append the overall
#%%
#output to excel   

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('output.xlsx')
sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
for i in range(0,len(output2)):
    for j in range(0,len(output2[i])):
        sheet.cell(row=i+3, column = j+1).value = str(output2[i][j])
wb.save('output.xlsx')
wb.close()
```