# Python: json response to csv?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am calling an API (https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=10) that gives the following response:

> {"Response":"Success","Type":100,"Aggregated":false,"Data":[{"time":1561852800,"close":10769.05,"high":12200.02,"low":10677.83,"open":11884.1,"volumefrom":80893.36,"volumeto":917158052.37},{"time":1561939200,"close":10591.87,"high":11207,"low":10006.43,"open":10769.05,"volumefrom":115739.97,"volumeto":1225129699.57},{"time":1562025600,"close":10844.13,"high":10927.6,"low":9678.1,"open":10591.87,"volumefrom":120994.95,"volumeto":1239524970.43},{"time":1562112000,"close":11981.61,"high":12009.59,"low":10841.91,"open":10844.13,"volumefrom":115565.16,"volumeto":1313585829.89},{"time":1562198400,"close":11156.52,"high":12055.11,"low":11067.68,"open":11981.61,"volumefrom":71141.03,"volumeto":831236841.56},{"time":1562284800,"close":10993.25,"high":11435.38,"low":10787.94,"open":11156.52,"volumefrom":66066.75,"volumeto":734424868.07},{"time":1562371200,"close":11248.94,"high":11709.27,"low":10985.4,"open":10993.25,"volumefrom":48172.2,"volumeto":549769169.13},{"time":1562457600,"close":11474.28,"high":11605.43,"low":11109.42,"open":11248.94,"volumefrom":36847.21,"volumeto":418161890.29},{"time":1562544000,"close":12296.16,"high":12386.28,"low":11339.02,"open":11474.28,"volumefrom":63847.27,"volumeto":762033323.29},{"time":1562630400,"close":12537.38,"high":12808.06,"low":12117.31,"open":12296.16,"volumefrom":79366.56,"volumeto":990863142.59},{"time":1562716800,"close":12855.54,"high":12855.54,"low":12537.38,"open":12537.38,"volumefrom":0,"volumeto":0}],"TimeTo":1562716800,"TimeFrom":1561852800,"FirstValueInArray":true,"ConversionType":{"type":"direct","conversionSymbol":""},"RateLimit":{},"HasWarning":false}

I need to convert this to a csv with columns for `time`, `close`, `high`, `low`, `open`, `volumefrom` and `volumeto` per the above. How should this be done? I've tried some existing answers for converting json to csv but they don't work in this case.

Comment: Once you have extracted the data using e.g. `json.loads(my_response)["Data"]` then this question becomes a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086973/how-do-i-convert-this-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-csv-file, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43138628/convert-list-of-dict-to-csv-in-python, and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy to do with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# Parse the json string to a python dictionary
data = json.loads(json_data)

# The desired data is in the `Data` field, use pandas to construct the data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data["Data"])

# Save to a csv file
df.to_csv("result.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not mention the use of a file, I simply generated the comma seperated values without the csv library. However, this could also have been done with [it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

```py
import requests
import json

r = requests.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=10")

# this is assuming the response has no errors and is status code 200
data = json.loads(r.text)

# in csv the headers are conventionally the first row
csv_data = "time, close, high, low, open"

for row in data["Data"]:

    # since the order is specific, select the values from the row in that order
    row_data = [row["time"], row["close"], row["high"], row["low"], row["open"]]

    # here I am using list comprehension to convert all the data from the row to a string
    # then I use the .join method to concatonate all these values as one comma seperated list
    csv_row = ", ".join([str(j) for j in row_data])

    csv_data += "\n" + csv_row

# here is your data
print(csv_data)
```

#### Documentation Links

- [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v1.0.0/) - A commonly used, friendly wrapper around python's request library.
- [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) - A more compact way of generating lists in python, and also slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! This should work for you! Feel free to ask any additional questions, I've tried to keep everything commented and reasonably neat. c:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json, csv

# Here is our input string/response. You can replace this!
responseString = '{"Response":"Success","Type":100,"Aggregated":false,"Data":[{"time":1561852800,"close":10769.05,"high":12200.02,"low":10677.83,"open":11884.1,"volumefrom":80893.36,"volumeto":917158052.37},{"time":1561939200,"close":10591.87,"high":11207,"low":10006.43,"open":10769.05,"volumefrom":115739.97,"volumeto":1225129699.57},{"time":1562025600,"close":10844.13,"high":10927.6,"low":9678.1,"open":10591.87,"volumefrom":120994.95,"volumeto":1239524970.43},{"time":1562112000,"close":11981.61,"high":12009.59,"low":10841.91,"open":10844.13,"volumefrom":115565.16,"volumeto":1313585829.89},{"time":1562198400,"close":11156.52,"high":12055.11,"low":11067.68,"open":11981.61,"volumefrom":71141.03,"volumeto":831236841.56},{"time":1562284800,"close":10993.25,"high":11435.38,"low":10787.94,"open":11156.52,"volumefrom":66066.75,"volumeto":734424868.07},{"time":1562371200,"close":11248.94,"high":11709.27,"low":10985.4,"open":10993.25,"volumefrom":48172.2,"volumeto":549769169.13},{"time":1562457600,"close":11474.28,"high":11605.43,"low":11109.42,"open":11248.94,"volumefrom":36847.21,"volumeto":418161890.29},{"time":1562544000,"close":12296.16,"high":12386.28,"low":11339.02,"open":11474.28,"volumefrom":63847.27,"volumeto":762033323.29},{"time":1562630400,"close":12537.38,"high":12808.06,"low":12117.31,"open":12296.16,"volumefrom":79366.56,"volumeto":990863142.59},{"time":1562716800,"close":12855.54,"high":12855.54,"low":12537.38,"open":12537.38,"volumefrom":0,"volumeto":0}],"TimeTo":1562716800,"TimeFrom":1561852800,"FirstValueInArray":true,"ConversionType":{"type":"direct","conversionSymbol":""},"RateLimit":{},"HasWarning":false}'

# Turn the response into JSON and only grab the 'Data' list.
responseString = json.loads(responseString)['Data']

# Open us a new file!
with open('output.csv', 'w') as output_csv_file:
    # Create us a new csv_object using the keys of the data as fieldnames.
    csv_object = csv.DictWriter(output_csv_file, fieldnames=responseString[0].keys())

    # For each row of data in the JSON, print it and write it to the CSV.
    for row in responseString:
        print(row)
        csv_object.writerow(row)

# Automatically close CSV file/object and print "Done!"
print("Done!")
```